# pythonのプログラムで TypeError: __init__()acces tokenのエラーについて

Tags: python

下記のプログラムを使って、pythonからweiboの投稿を取得したいです。

プログラムの内容

```
from weibo import APIClient    # suppose you are using Twitter

APP_KEY = '294703483'            # app key
APP_SECRET = 'a2ef9de0a580edb7a26daf2804d27624'      # app secret
CALLBACK_URL = 'https://api.weibo.com/oauth2/authorize'  # callback url

client = APIClient(app_key=APP_KEY, app_secret=APP_SECRET,redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL,
           access_token='2.00skPOWG0zpXw_e8253b9b7c9GKIdE', expires=1635772406)

print client.statuses.user_timeline.get()
```

プログラム実行
エラーメッセージ

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "salsa.py", line 9, in <module>
access_token='2.00skPOWG0zpXw_e8253b9b7c9GKIdE', expires=1635772406)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'access_token'
```

pythonからsinaweibodyのプログラムについては[michaelliao](https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy/wiki/OAuth2-HOWTO) /[sinaweibopy](https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy)から情報を取得しました。

[ACCESTOKEN](http://blog.csdn.net/minenki/article/details/8836293)とexpiresはプログラムを実行して取得しました。
accestokenは[weiboguide](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lingwang/weiboguide/)でも取得できます。

input the code: e983face8da18b92e14397505b02882b
Successfully get access_token: 2.00skPOWG0zpXw_e8253b9b7c9GKIdE
Successfully get expires_in: 1635771889

エラーが何故起きるかわかる方がいれば教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ある関数を呼び出し時、存在しないパラメーターを指定されると、そのエラー

```
TypeError: 関数名 got an unexpected keyword argument 引数名
```

は発生します。

例えば

```
def foo(a, b):
    pass

foo(a=0, b=1) # OK
foo(a=0, b=1, c=2) # エラー発生、c は foo のパラメーターではありません
```

ご質問の中のプロジェクトの README によって、`access_token` は `APIClient` のパラメーターではなく、`APIClient` のインスタンスから `.request_access_token` の関数で取得するべきです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。.request_access_token の関数について良くわかるませんclient = APIClientのところをrequest_access_tokenに変更することですか。

Comment: @FannyZhingre  [プロジェクトの wiki](https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy/wiki/OAuth2-HOWTO#%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E7%AE%80%E4%BB%8B) に `access_token` の使用について、`client.set_access_token(access_token, expires_in)` の例があります。しかし README の中確かにもう一つ `APIClient(TwitterMixin, app_key=APP_KEY, app_secret=APP_SECRET, redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL, access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN, expires=EXPIRES_TIME)` もあります (`access_token` を渡した)。もしかしたら誤記ですが、issue を送信して質問するほうがよろしいでしょうか。